# Get a list of instances based on cidr range

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apis-explorer

I want to get a list of instances through GCP rest API by filtering the ones which have aliasIpRanges within ipCidrRange.

I tried `networkInterfaces.aliasIpRanges.ipCidrRange = <requiredrange>`, which works with GCP Python SDK, but doesn't work directly with rest API call.

It says `Invalid value for field 'filter': 'networkInterfaces.aliasIpRanges.ipCidrRange=\"\"'. Invalid list filter expression.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/129726523) about the 'instances.list' method of the rest API. You can use the 'gcloud' CLI as a workaround until the bug gets fixed, and here are one example based in your API query.

```
gcloud compute instances list --project [PROJECT_NAME] --filter='networkInterfaces.aliasIpRanges.ipCidrRange="[REQUIRED_RANGE]"'
```

Comment: Thank you @amonaco. Yea currently I'm using gcloud CLI. But was hoping to have an rest API.